# I want to call ajax on delete button of dialog box in zf.

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am getting dialogbox on click of delete link. but the problem is when I click delete link,it delete related row by itself clicking on yes. I want to control Yes and No button of dialog box using Ajax in zf view/index.phtml and delete action of controller. Please help me.and thank you :)

```
"Yes": function() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/therapyServices/delete",
dataType: "json",
data: "id="+id,
success: "Congratulations" }); },
"No" : function(){ 
$btnvalid= false;
(this).dialog("close"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in document.ready function something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#idOfYesLink").click(function()
{
     //call ajax here to delete row from database
});

$("#idOfNoLink").click(function()
{
     //Close dialog box and do no action
});

});
```

may this be helpful
guide me if I am wrong
Thank you

Comment: $(function () {$("#dialog").dialog({buttons: {
                                     "Yes": function() {
                                              $.ajax({
                                                  type: "POST",
                                                  url: "/therapyServices/",
                                                  dataType: "json",
                                                  data: "id="+id,
                                                  success:"Congratulation" }); } }});